# EF 6.2 - table with 2 navigation properties referencing to 1 table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, web, navigation-properties

I use EF 6.2 Database first. I have table dbo.Users and table dbo.Friends.

```
dbo.User:
ID (PK)
FirstName
LastName


dbo.Friends
FriendshipID (PK)
UserId
FriendID
```

both of UserID and FriendID are references as ForeignKey to dbo.User - ID. Then I have 2 virtual properties on Class Friends

```
public virtual User User_FriendID { get; set; }
public virtual User User_UserID { get; set; }
```

Selecting data and navigation properties works well. When I add a new record to table dbo.Friends

```
Friends fs = new Friends { UserId = 1, FriendId = 2};
entities.Friends.Add(fs);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

Code `entities.Friends.Add(fs)` creates a new record and fill only `public virtual User User_UserID { get; set; }` and that is the problem because I need both virtual properties filled.

[proof of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxcYr.png)

Can anyone solve it?

Comment: you mean that the friendId doesn't have value in database?

Comment: no, in database is everythink OK. After I create the new record (entities.SaveChanges) I send object "fs" to the next operation. Object "fs" has filled property User_UserID, but NULL property User_FriendID. Check the picture "proof of problem" i my post.

Comment: How are you retrieving the data (query)? Including the children?
  dbSet.Friends.Include("User_UserID").Include("Users.FriendID").Where(...).FirstOrDefault();  Explicit vs. Lazy Loading (Virtual).

Comment: i save new record to database (entities.Friends.Add(fs);) After that I got to "fs" objetct virtual property User_UserID but not User_FriendID